# Animating a painted object

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

I've gone through and made classes for my objects and calls to them in my paint component, but I cant actually get them to move. Here is my move and check walls program that is in the object class:

```
public void move()
{
    ballX += dx;
    ballY += dy;

    checkWalls();
}

//bounce of top/bottom, pass through left/right
public void checkWalls() {
    //left-right
    if(ballX > w) {
        ballX = -diam;
    }
    else if(ballX < -diam) {
        ballX = w;
    }

    //top-bottom
    if(ballY < 0) {
        dy *= -1;
    }
    else if(ballY + diam > h) {
        dy *= -1;
    }
}
```

And here is my call to them:

```
while(true) // infinite loop 
{
    jelly1.move();

    frame.repaint();

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Also i feel the need to mention i have a background and a background component. The while(true) is in the background component because that's where the objects are created. And the frame is set visible in the background where the main method is.

Paint component is as follows:

```
public class BackgroundComponent extends JComponent {
    Jellyfish jelly1;
    Jellyfish jelly2;
    Jellyfish jelly3;
    Diver diver;

    public BackgroundComponent() {
        diver = new Diver(100, 300);
        jelly1 = new Jellyfish(450, 450);
        jelly2 = new Jellyfish(150, 300);
        jelly3 = new Jellyfish(350, 75);
        diver = new Diver(100, 300);
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //Drawing instructions go here
        //Recover Graphics2D
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        //Make gradient
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        Color color1 = Color.CYAN;
        Color color2 = Color.BLACK;
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
        g2.setPaint(gp);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        //Constructs rectangles on edge of screen and draws them
        Rectangle box = new Rectangle(0,0,75,700);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2.fill(box);
        Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(625, 0, 75, 700);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2.fill(box2);
        //Draws lines, with a stroke of 5, over rectangles
        Line2D.Double segment = new Line2D.Double(10, 0, 10, 700);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.draw(segment);
        Line2D.Double segment2 = new Line2D.Double(30, 0, 30, 700);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.draw(segment2);
        Line2D.Double segment3 = new Line2D.Double(50, 0, 50, 700);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.draw(segment3);
        Line2D.Double segment4 = new Line2D.Double(70, 0, 70, 700);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.draw(segment4);
        Line2D.Double segment5 = new Line2D.Double(690, 0, 690, 700);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.draw(segment5);
        Line2D.Double segment6 = new Line2D.Double(670, 0, 670, 700);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.draw(segment6);
        Line2D.Double segment7 = new Line2D.Double(650, 0, 650, 700);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.draw(segment7);
        Line2D.Double segment8 = new Line2D.Double(630, 0, 630, 700);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.draw(segment8);
        //Draws rectangle around title with thick boarder
        Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(40,40,620,75);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2.draw(box3);
        //Drawing text
        String title = "Through the Depths";
        //Sets font, font size, and color
        g.setFont(new Font("Purisa", Font.BOLD, 50));
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2.drawString(title, (50), 100);
        //Places same text slightly up and over
        g.setFont(new Font("Purisa", Font.BOLD, 50));
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.drawString(title, 53, 97);
        //Draws ellipses with a stroke of 2 (these are the bubbles)
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(450, 200, 150, 150);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2.draw(ellipse);
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(510, 375, 90, 90);
        g2.draw(ellipse2);
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(470, 485, 70, 70);
        g2.draw(ellipse3);
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse4 = new Ellipse2D.Double(510, 580, 45, 45);
        g2.draw(ellipse4);
        // Draws curves for bubbles
        QuadCurve2D q = new QuadCurve2D.Float();
        q.setCurve(548, 210, 607, 240, 590, 295);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g2.draw(q);
        QuadCurve2D q2 = new QuadCurve2D.Float();
        q2.setCurve(575, 387, 607, 415, 585, 445);
        g2.draw(q2);
        QuadCurve2D q3 = new QuadCurve2D.Float();
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        q3.setCurve(515, 493, 545, 511, 528, 540);      
        g2.draw(q3);
        QuadCurve2D q4 = new QuadCurve2D.Float();
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        q4.setCurve(538, 585, 558, 595, 545, 617);
        g2.draw(q4);
        // Sets color to pink before drawing jellyfish
        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
        //draws jellyfish
        jelly1.draw(g);
        jelly2.draw(g);
        jelly3.draw(g);
        // Draws diver
        diver.draw(g);
        while(true) // infinite loop 
        {
        jelly1.move();


        repaint();

        try
        {
        Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: BTW: `ballX = ballX % windowWidth` will make it wrap around

Comment: What thread does the `while(true)` run on? This is very important information. (edit: We're also missing your paint routine. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.)

Comment: its runs on the background component. and i didn't include paint component because its kinda long seeing as it also has all my other objects. im trying to move one object first before moving on to the next ones

Comment: also yes i want it to wrap around

Comment: *"its runs on the background component."* - so nothing paints or update then? You might consider having a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: *"..i didn't include paint component because its kinda long"* So kinda shorten it to a [mcve]. There are now two votes to close for 'lack of MCVE' so don't delay at preparing and posting one.

Answer (score 1):

`while(true){ ... }` and `Thread.Sleep` inside a `paintComponent` implementation is completely the wrong way of doing things. By doing this, you are blocking the [Event Dispatching Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) completely which means that your UI will no longer be updated properly and the UI will no longer be responsive.

What you should do:

- Remove the `while(true){ ... }` loop from the `paintComponent` override
- Create a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), set it to run every 10 milliseconds
- In the `ActionListener.actionPerformed` implementation - the action that will be performed each 10 ms - move the *jelly* and call for a `repaint`
- Start this timer after initialization is done, eg at the end of your constructor or initialization method (not paintComponent).
- Stop the timer when it is no longer needed

---

Simplified example for this Timer, based on your snippet:

```
new javax.swing.Timer( 10, new ActionListener( ) {
    @override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        jelly1.move();
        repaint();
    }
}).start();
```